# Onclick function to change SLDS vertical navbar to active

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, slds, help

[image]

Iam working on a visualforce page with SLDS
As you can see option B is highlighted as li class has slds-is-active on it. But it remains the same as it is throughout. Is there a way I can change the state of options to active if i click on it? If you have any approach please let me know.

Thanks

Sample Code:

````
        <li class="slds-nav-vertical__item">
          <apex:commandLink styleClass="slds-nav-vertical__action" value="A" action="{!basic_detailsclick}"/>
        </li>
        <li class="slds-nav-vertical__item slds-is-active">
        <apex:commandLink styleClass="slds-nav-vertical__action" value="B" action="{!rsclick}"/>
        </li>
        <li class="slds-nav-vertical__item">
          <apex:commandLink styleClass="slds-nav-vertical__action" value="C" action="{!possible_refClick}"/>
        </li> ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use additional properties to set the value server-side:

```
    <li class="slds-nav-vertical__item {!if(valueA,'slds-is-active','')}">
      <apex:commandLink styleClass="slds-nav-vertical__action" value="A" action="{!basic_detailsclick}"/>
    </li>
    <li class="slds-nav-vertical__item {!if(valueB,'slds-is-active','')}">
    <apex:commandLink styleClass="slds-nav-vertical__action" value="B" action="{!rsclick}"/>
    </li>
    <li class="slds-nav-vertical__item {!if(valueC,'slds-is-active','')}">
      <apex:commandLink styleClass="slds-nav-vertical__action" value="C" action="{!possible_refClick}"/>
    </li>
```

Or you can do it client-side:

```
<ul onlick="updateActive(event)">
<li class="slds-nav-vertical__item">
  <apex:commandLink styleClass="slds-nav-vertical__action" value="A" action="{!basic_detailsclick}"/>
</li>
<li class="slds-nav-vertical__item">
<apex:commandLink styleClass="slds-nav-vertical__action" value="B" action="{!rsclick}"/>
</li>
<li class="slds-nav-vertical__item">
  <apex:commandLink styleClass="slds-nav-vertical__action" value="C" action="{!possible_refClick}"/>
</li>
</ul>
```

---

```
<script>
function updateActive(event) {
  let elements = event.currentTarget.querySelectorAll('li');
  [...elements].forEach(element => element.classList.removeClass('slds-is-active'));
  element.target.closest('li').classList.addClass('slds-is-active');
}
</script>
```

You'll need to set some additional state if you do this, because rerendering will wipe out the extra classes.